PowerShell script to fetch Azure storage account based on tag name & value
I have a requirement to fetch storage account details with size in all subscriptions based on tag value & Name using PowerShell.
I'm using the below Get-Azstorageaccount module to fetch the details which is giving me the output with tags but I want to modify the script to filter out with specific tag name & value also with storage account size.
# Authenticate to Azure
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant 'xxxxx'-UseDeviceAuthentication
 
# Get all subscriptions in the current tenant
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

# Define the Azure tag name
$tagName = "business"
$tagValue = "xyz"

# Filter storage accounts based on the tag
#$filteredStorageAccounts = $storageAccounts | Where-Object { $_.Tags[$tagName] } 

# Initialize an array to store storage account details
$storageAccounts = @()
 
foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    Write-Output "Processing subscription $($subscription.Name)..."

    # Set the current subscription context
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id | Out-Null
    try {
        
        
        # Get all storage accounts in the subscription (Where-Object { $_.Tags[$tagName] -eq $tagValue })
        
        $storageAccounts += Get-AzStorageAccount | ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                SubscriptionName   = $subscription.Name
                ResourceGroupName  = $_.ResourceGroupName
                StorageAccountName = $_.StorageAccountName
                Location           = $_.PrimaryLocation
                AccountType        = $_.AccountType
                CreationTime       = $_.CreationTime
                TagName            = $_.Tags
            }
        }
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Error fetching storage accounts in subscription $($subscription.Name): $_"
    }
}
 
# Output the results
if ($storageAccounts) {
    $storageAccounts | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
else {
    Write-Output "No storage accounts found in any subscription."
}



PowerShell script to fetch Azure storage account based on tag name & value

You can use the below script to fetch Azure storage account based on tag name & used capacity size also.
Script:
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant 'xxxxx'-UseDeviceAuthentication
# Get all subscriptions
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

# Define the tag key and value to filter by
$tagKey = "xxx"
$tagValue = "xxxx"

# Initialize an array to store the results
$results = @()

foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    # Set the current subscription context
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id

    # Get all storage accounts in the current subscription
    $storageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount | Where-Object { $_.Tags[$tagKey] -eq $tagValue }

    foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) {
        # Get the metrics for the storage account
        $resourceId = "/subscriptions/$($subscription.Id)/resourceGroups/$($storageAccount.ResourceGroupName)/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/$($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"
        $uri = "https://management.azure.com$resourceId/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01&metricnames=UsedCapacity&aggregation=Average"

        try {
            $response = Invoke-AzRestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri
            $metrics = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
            $usedCapacityMetric = $metrics.value | Where-Object { $_.name.value -eq "UsedCapacity" }

            if ($usedCapacityMetric) {
                $averageCapacity = $usedCapacityMetric.timeseries.data.average | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
            } else {
                $averageCapacity = 0
            }
        } catch {
            Write-Warning "Failed to retrieve metrics for storage account: $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"
            $averageCapacity = 0
        }

        # Add the storage account details and size to the results
        $results += [PSCustomObject]@{
            SubscriptionId   = $subscription.Id
            SubscriptionName = $subscription.Name
            ResourceGroup    = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName
            StorageAccount   = $storageAccount.StorageAccountName
            UsedCapacityInBytes = $averageCapacity
        }
    }
}

# Output the results
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize

Output:
SubscriptionId                       SubscriptionName                      ResourceGroup StorageAccount UsedCapacityInBytes
--------------                       ----------------                      ------------- -------------- -------------------
158b834xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5-f21815dd048f xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx venkatesan-rg venkat6781                75622151
158b834xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx5-f21815dd048f xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx xxxxxxxxxxx venkatesan-rg venkat891                   543896


Reference:
Metrics - List - REST API (Azure Monitor) | Microsoft Learn
Updated Script:
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant 'xxxxx' -UseDeviceAuthentication
# Get all subscriptions
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

# Define the tag key to filter by
$tagKey = "createdby"

# Initialize an array to store the results
$results = @()

foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    # Set the current subscription context
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id

    # Get all storage accounts in the current subscription
    $storageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount | Where-Object { $_.Tags.ContainsKey($tagKey) }

    foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) {
        # Get the metrics for the storage account
        $resourceId = "/subscriptions/$($subscription.Id)/resourceGroups/$($storageAccount.ResourceGroupName)/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/$($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"
        $uri = "https://management.azure.com$resourceId/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01&metricnames=UsedCapacity&aggregation=Average"

        try {
            $response = Invoke-AzRestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri
            $metrics = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
            $usedCapacityMetric = $metrics.value | Where-Object { $_.name.value -eq "UsedCapacity" }

            if ($usedCapacityMetric) {
                $averageCapacity = $usedCapacityMetric.timeseries.data.average | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
            } else {
                $averageCapacity = 0
            }
        } catch {
            Write-Warning "Failed to retrieve metrics for storage account: $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"
            $averageCapacity = 0
        }

        # Add the storage account details, size, and tags to the results
        $results += [PSCustomObject]@{
            SubscriptionId       = $subscription.Id
            SubscriptionName     = $subscription.Name
            ResourceGroup        = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName
            StorageAccount       = $storageAccount.StorageAccountName
            UsedCapacityInBytes  = $averageCapacity
            TagName              = $tagKey
            TagValue             = $storageAccount.Tags[$tagKey]
        }
    }
}

# Output the results
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize

Output:
SubscriptionId                       SubscriptionName                      ResourceGroup StorageAccount UsedCapacityInBytes TagName   TagValue
--------------                       ----------------                      ------------- -------------- ------------------- -------   --------
15xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx Subscription venkatesan-rg venkat6781                 6123454 createdby venkat  
15xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx Subscription venkatesan-rg venkat891                   693954 createdby venkat  


Thanks Venkatesan, The script is giving results for storage accounts filtered out based on the tags, but how do I get the tag name and tag value  in the results ?

Add tag name and tag value in results like $results += [PSCustomObject]@{             SubscriptionId       = $subscription.Id             SubscriptionName     = $subscription.Name             ResourceGroup        = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName             StorageAccount       = $storageAccount.StorageAccountName             UsedCapacityInBytes  = $averageCapacity             TagName              = $tagKey             TagValue             = $tagValue         } in the above script

I have tried the same but this gives me the defined tag name and tag value in the variables. For example I have to define the $tagname  as business and the code should filter out the storage accounts and get the output with storage account details along with Tag Name & Tag Value (without defining tag value here as variable).

Check the Updated script It will define tag name filter out the storage accounts and get the output with storage account details along with Tag Name & Tag Value.

@Nolan1513 Hope this will address your issue.

The script worked and able to fetch the required content. Thank you @Venkatesan

@Nolan1513 Glad to know it worked : )

@venkatesan, Could you provide any inputs to list containers along with the storage accounts with the above script ?

Raise it with new question and add more points what you want?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78758699/running-powershell-script-in-all-azure-subscriptions/78768001#78768001
Check this answer. @Nolan1513

Try below:
# Authenticate to Azure
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant 'xxxxx'-UseDeviceAuthentication
 
# Get all subscriptions in the current tenant
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

# Define the Azure tag name
$tagName = "Owner"
$tagValue = "wenbo"
$storageAccountSkuName = "Standard_RAGRS"

$storageAccounts = @()
 
foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    Write-Output "Processing subscription $($subscription.Name)..."

    # Set the current subscription context
    Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id | Out-Null
    try {

        $res = Get-AzResource -ResourceType 'microsoft.storage/storageaccounts' -ExpandProperties | Where-Object {$_.Tags.Keys -contains $tagName -and $_.Tags[$tagName] -eq $tagValue} | Where-Object {$_.Sku.Name -eq $storageAccountSkuName} | Select-Object -Property ResourceGroupName, Name,Location, Tags, ResourceType, @{n = 'Size'; e= {$_.Sku.Name}}, @{n = 'CreationTime'; e={$_.Properties.creationTime}}
        $storageAccounts += $res
    }
    catch {
        Write-Error "Error fetching storage accounts in subscription $($subscription.Name): $_"
    }
}
 
# Output the results
if ($storageAccounts) {
    $storageAccounts | Format-Table -AutoSize
}
else {
    Write-Output "No storage accounts found in any subscription."
}

