Running PowerShell script in all Azure subscriptions
I have a reference script below from (stackoverflow) which will fetch the storage account container details. it will output the subscription, storageaccount, container name and RG name.
Connect-AzAccount -Tenant 'xxxx' -UseDeviceAuthentication

#Set-AzContext -Subscription xxxx


$context = Get-AzContext
import-module az.resources

Get-AzSubscription | ForEach-Object {
    # Set the context Details using Set-AzContext Command which is equalent to the az account set CLI Command
    $_ | Set-AzContext
    $subscriptionName = $_.Name
      #<RUN YOUR SCRIPTS HERE>#

$storageAccounts = Get-AzResource -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts' 
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$saUsage = New-Object -TypeName System.Collections.ArrayList

 foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) {

   #list containers
   $conatiners= Get-AzRmStorageContainer -ResourceGroupName $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName -StorageAccountName $storageAccount.Name 

     if($conatiners -ne $null){
          foreach($container in $conatiners){
            $StorageAccountDetails = [ordered]@{
                    SubscriptionName = $context.Subscription.Name
                    SubscrpitionID = $context.Subscription.Id
                    StorageAccountName = $storageAccount.Name
                    ContainerName = $container.Name
                    ResourceGroup = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName
                    Location = $storageAccount.Location
               }
             $saUsage.add((New-Object psobject -Property $StorageAccountDetails))  | Out-Null   
            }     
      }else{
      
        $StorageAccountDetails = [ordered]@{
                SubscriptionName = $context.Subscription.Name
                SubscrpitionID = $context.Subscription.Id
                StorageAccountName = $storageAccount.Name
                ContainerName = $null
                ResourceGroup = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName
                Location = $storageAccount.Location      
         }
        $saUsage.add((New-Object psobject -Property $StorageAccountDetails)) | Out-Null
     }     
  }
}

$saUsage | Format-Table -AutoSize

I want the script to list the storage account container details and storage account size from all the subscriptions in my tenant filtered out by tagkey.

Not sure what the question is here. You are already running Set-AzContext with each subscription you are getting? Can you explain what issue you are facing?

Try using azure resource graph, just search it in google. it will easily achieve your goal instead of coding too much.

@sudhir karamchand Check if above provided solution works for you? Let me know if I can be helpful here anyway with further input?


I want the script to list the storage account container details and storage account size from all the subscriptions in my tenant filtered out by tagkey.

You can use the below script to get the list of storage accounts with usage, container name and filtered out by tag key.
Script:

Connect-AzAccount -Tenant 'xxxxx' -UseDeviceAuthentication
# Get all subscriptions
$subscriptions = Get-AzSubscription

# Define the tag key to filter by
$tagKey = "createdby"

# Initialize an array to store the results
$results = @()

foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    # Set the current subscription context
    Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId $subscription.Id

    # Get all storage accounts in the current subscription
    $storageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount | Where-Object { $_.Tags.ContainsKey($tagKey) }

    foreach ($storageAccount in $storageAccounts) {
        # Get the metrics for the storage account
        $resourceId = "/subscriptions/$($subscription.Id)/resourceGroups/$($storageAccount.ResourceGroupName)/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/$($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"
        $uri = "https://management.azure.com$resourceId/providers/Microsoft.Insights/metrics?api-version=2023-10-01&metricnames=UsedCapacity&aggregation=Average"

        try {
            $response = Invoke-AzRestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri
            $metrics = $response.Content | ConvertFrom-Json
            $usedCapacityMetric = $metrics.value | Where-Object { $_.name.value -eq "UsedCapacity" }

            if ($usedCapacityMetric) {
                $averageCapacity = $usedCapacityMetric.timeseries.data.average | Measure-Object -Sum | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Sum
            } else {
                $averageCapacity = 0
            }
        } catch {
            Write-Warning "Failed to retrieve metrics for storage account: $($storageAccount.StorageAccountName)"
            $averageCapacity = 0
        }

        $ctx = $storageAccount.Context
        $containers = Get-AzStorageContainer -Context $ctx

        foreach ($container in $containers) {
        $results += [PSCustomObject]@{
            SubscriptionId       = $subscription.Id
            SubscriptionName     = $subscription.Name
            ResourceGroup        = $storageAccount.ResourceGroupName
            StorageAccount       = $storageAccount.StorageAccountName
            ContainerName        = $container.Name
            UsedCapacityInBytes  = $averageCapacity
            TagName              = $tagKey
            TagValue             = $storageAccount.Tags[$tagKey]
        }
      }
    }
}

# Output the results
$results | Format-Table -AutoSize

Output:
SubscriptionId                       SubscriptionName                      ResourceGroup StorageAccount ContainerName UsedCapacityInBytes TagName   TagValue
--------------                       ----------------                      ------------- -------------- ------------- ------------------- -------   --------
15xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx Subscription venkatesan-rg venkat6781     data                     81178955 createdby venkat  
15xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx Subscription venkatesan-rg venkat6781     test                     81178955 createdby venkat  
15xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx Subscription venkatesan-rg venkat891      results                   7577683 createdby venkat  
15xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxf xxxxxx xxxxxx xxxxxxxxxx Subscription venkatesan-rg venkat891      sample                    7577683 createdby venkat  


Reference:
PowerShell script to fetch Azure storage account based on tag name & value - Stack Overflow by me.
